# How to persist inverse-of relation through order, find, where, etc call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Given the following classes with **inverse-has-many-association**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :accounts, inverse_of: :user
end

class Account < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And any given User object loaded as follows:

```
u = User.first
u.some_not_saved_variable = "123"
```

The following code shows that the inverse relation is not persisted after executing a new sql statement (order hits the database):

```
u.accounts.first.user.some_not_saved_variable                       #=> "123"
u.accounts.order(:created_at).first.user.some_not_saved_variable    #=> nil
```

**How to I make sure that my user object still remains the same after having executed an order, find, where, etc call?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist the objects attribute but do not want to save the record then you can try using `attributes=(new_attributes)` or `assign_attributes(new_attributes, options = {})`

In your case:

```
u = User.first
u.attributes= :some_not_saved_variable => "123"
```

or

```
u = User.first
u.assign_attributes :some_not_saved_variable => "123"
```

sources:  [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes) and [attributes=](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/attributes=)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible...

the `inverse_of` allows you to get the user object without pulling the database again, so the unsaved value of `some_not_saved_variable` (123) will persist.

However, if you call `order`, `find`, `where`, etc, a SQL will be generated and the stored data will replace the unsaved one.

Without `inverse_of`:

```
u.accounts.first.user.some_not_saved_variable
 #SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 #SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> "database value" #123 will be lost
```

Using `inverse_of`:

```
u.accounts.first.user.some_not_saved_variable
 #no SQL statement
=> "123" #123 persist
```

Calling `order`, `find`, `where`, etc:

```
u.accounts.order(:created_at).first.user.some_not_saved_variable 
#SQL to order by created_at
```

So, it will always access the database and the unsaved value will be replaced by the database one.